# php sum zero value to float number

Tags: php, floating-point-precision

I'm in trouble with this:

```
$price = 26,20;
$increase = 0,00;
$decrease = 0,00;

$result = ($price + $increase - $decrease);
```

Result becomes 26 instead of 26,20

Any idea?

Thnx!

Comment: I changed the decimal point delimiter from comma (which errored) to period and got the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) in case you need comma as decimal separator, see example below:

```
$price = 26.20;
$increase = 0.00;
$decrease = 0.00;

$result = ($price + $increase - $decrease);
echo number_format($result , 2, ',', '');
```